# Array Length returns undefined in Javascript - Laravel + Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I am working on a project using `Vue + Laravel` where I use `axios` for `AJAX` requests to get data from controllers and display it on the `js` end but while using nested `for loop` it does not work and I feel some strange behavior from the loop inside js.

Below is the function in `laravel controller` that returns data:

```
public function show(Notebook $notebook)
{
    $pages = $notebook->pages()->get();
    $slotsPerPage = count($pages->first()->slots);
    $noOfPages = count($pages);
    $pageDeleted = session()->has('pageDeleted') ? session()->pull('pageDeleted') : null;

    return [
            'notebook' => $notebook, 'slotsPerPage' => $slotsPerPage, 'noOfPages' => $noOfPages,
            'pages' => $pages->chunk(4), 'pageDeleted' => $pageDeleted
           ];
}
```

In the above code we can see that `pages => $pages->chunk(4)` that will return an array of records where each record in this array will contain exactly 4 records therefore I am running nested `for loops` in the `js` end to first loop through the `chunks` and then loop through the `records` in the chunks like the code below:

```
   for(var i=0; i < response.data['pages'].length; i++)
   {
       for(var x = 0; x < response.data['pages'][i].length; x++)
       {
           this.pages.push(response.data['pages'][i][x]);
       }
   }
```

In the above code suppose the `pages => chunk(4)` returned `6` records in total which are divided into two chunks where the first chunk contains `4` records and the other chunk contains `2` records so in the first iteration of the outer loop the code `response.data['pages'][i].length` should return `4` which is the length of the first chunk and in the second iteration of the loop the same code should return `2` as the `length` because it contains two records but here the issue is that the `length` in the second iteration returns `undefined` and only `4` records are pushed into the `this.pages` arrray.

Edit:

When I `console.log(response.data['pages']);`, I see this:

[image: Pages]

When I `console.log(response.data['pages'][i].length);` inside the outer loops, I see this :

[image: Length]

I hope I explained it well, any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: So did you check what `response.data['pages']` actually contains? Log it to console and inspect it, to _verify_ it actually contains the structure & data you thought it would.

Comment: @CBroe : Yes, I checked it, Six record are returned in two chunks, the first chunk contains four records and the second one contains two records, here the length returns `4` which is correct but in the second iteration the `length` returns `undefined`

Comment: Can you please show what that actually looks like, on the console?

Comment: P.s., what is the point of this? By the looks of it, you are pushing all of those individual pages to `this.pages`, so the result will be a flat array (of six elements, without your given example numbers) - so why did you chunk the data then in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe : I am chunking records because I need them as chunks in the other pages but  I should be able to fetch single rows out of the chunks here

Comment: @CBroe : I added the output of the console to the post

Comment: @CBroe : Yes I checked both, `response.data['pages']` return `6` records in two chunks, first chunk has `4` and the other has `2` but the length returns `4` and `undefined`

Comment: What you have under `1` appears not to be a proper array. Otherwise, it should show `Array(x)` there, same as for the `0` item. Can you show how that value gets transported from PHP to JS?

Comment: @CBroe : The `php` side is shown in the question.

Comment: So what did `$pages->chunk(4)` return on the PHP side then? Either that was not a standard two-dimensional array then to begin with, or something goes wrong when this data is passed over to JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe : That's weird ! The first chunk on php side has `App\Page` records without key/value pairs but in the second chunk it has key/value pairs like `4 => App\Page` and `5 => App\Page`

Answer (score 0):

if you use Laravel in backend i recemmend use api for send the data, i mean api.php

Can you try with return only the data for default, and later make filter in response.data.pages or response.data-xxx